# Data Align Global Variable

Tags: c, iar

I am clearly missing something obvious, but I am stumped:

I have one source file where I declare all of my global variables, and a header file that matches and makes them all extern. However, when I try to use a pragma provided by my IDE (IAR) to data align a variable there, it does not work. It is placing the variable at an address like 0x20027424. If I move the variable to local, it works fine; the address ends in 0.

What am I missing?

From **Vars.c**:

```
#pragma data_alignment=4
u16  g_uCompChk;
```

From **Vars.h**:

```
#pragma data_alignment=4
extern u16  g_uCompChk;
```

Comment: have you linked both files?

Comment: When dealing with implementation-defined things like #pragma, please post which compiler you are using

Comment: Yes, both files are linked. Added the specific compiler I'm using.

Comment: Please define "it does not work". How? And that pragma is only needed for the variable  definition in IAR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data_alignment = expression
```

should give an alignment in bytes, not in multiples of the object size.
So an alignment on 4 bytes boundary is to be expected. It seems everything is ok according to the example addresse you provided

Comment: I am confused: if it's 4-byte aligned (32 bits), then shouldn't the address end in 0?

Comment: @nobby Addresses are in bytes, so any address that divides exactly by 4 is 4 byte aligned. That means anything ending 0, 4, 8 or C is 4 byte aligned. Addresses ending in 0 are (also) 16 byte aligned.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was having a brain cramp and was thinking of flash pages.